# Linq Left join query in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Doing some stuff linq left join query but facing some problem. Not able to get proper result following sql query need to convert into linq

```
INSERT INTO tbl_service_order_attributes_versioning(ServiceOrderNo, AttributeId, AttributeValue, parentid, AttributeType, Dt_Stamp, VERSION)
    SELECT 
        T.ServiceOrderNo, T.COIID, T.COI_Identifier, 
        @pid, 'MBM', getDate(), @ORDERVERSION 
    FROM 
        #temp1 T                                                    
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_service_order_attributes_versioning O WITH(NOLOCK) 
            ON T.ServiceOrderNo =  O.ServiceOrderNo COLLATE database_default
            AND T.COIID = O.AttributeID
            AND O.PARENTID = @pid  
    WHERE 
        O.ServiceOrderNo IS NULL
```

I have converted this query into a Linq query:

```
var soiAttr = (from s in ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING
               where s.ParentId == parentId
               select s).ToList();

var resultJoinCOI = (from soaI in soiAttr
                     join iFoi in listFOI on soaI.ServiceOrderNo equals iFoi.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier
                     where iFoi.coiId == soaI.AttributeId && 
                           iFoi.parentId == parentId && 
                           soaI.ServiceOrderNo == null
                     select iFoi).ToList();

if (resultJoinCOI.Count > 0)
{
    var listToInsert = (from item in resultJoinCOI
                        select new TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING
                                    {
                                        ServiceOrderNo = item.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier,
                                        AttributeId = item.coiId,
                                        AttributeValue = item.coiIdentifier,
                                        ParentId = parentId,
                                        AttributeType = "MBM",
                                        DT_Stamp = DateTime.Now,
                                        VERSION = orderVersion
                                    });
                ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING.AddRange(listToInsert);
                ctxParser.SaveChanges();
            }
```

The code is executed but result are not correct.

Comment: What was the expected result, and what was the result you got?

Comment: in sql there is LEFT JOIN how to do in linq. bcz that linq query soaI.ServiceOrderNo == null its not correct.

Comment: Kinda hard to help if we don't know the types of your objects. Even if we did, though, the expected result is still an incognito. What are you expecting to receieve at `resultJoinCOI`? Also, `join` is an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT`, so a simple conditional of `key equals null`might not be enough

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  DefaultIfEmpty (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx). Here's a reading from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

In your case it would be something like:

```
var resultJoinCOI = (
                from iFoi in listFOI
                join soaI in soiAttr on iFoi.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier equals soaI.ServiceOrderNo into res
                from subIFoi in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where iFoi.coiId == soaI.AttributeId && iFoi.parentId == parentId && subIFoi == null
                select iFoi).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Following code that execute successfully. and getting right result.

```
 var soiAttr = (from s in ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING
                       where s.ParentId == parentId
                       select s).ToList();

 var resultJoinCOI = (from iFoi in listFOI
                             join soaI in soiAttr on
                             new
                             {
                                 ServiceOrderNo = iFoi.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier,
                                 AttributeId = iFoi.coiId
                             }
                             equals new
                             {
                                 ServiceOrderNo = soaI.ServiceOrderNo,
                                 AttributeId = soaI.AttributeId
                             }
                             into res
                             from subFoi in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new
                             {
                                 fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier = iFoi.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier,
                                 coiId = iFoi.coiId,
                                 coiIdentifier = iFoi.coiIdentifier,
                                 AttributeId = subFoi == null ? 0 : subFoi.AttributeId,
                                 ParentId = subFoi == null ? parentId : subFoi.ParentId,  
                                 ServiceOrderNo = subFoi == null ? string.Empty: subFoi.ServiceOrderNo
                             });

  if (resultJoinCOI != null)
        {
            if (resultJoinCOI.Count() > 0)
            {
                var listToInsert = (from item in resultJoinCOI
                                    select new TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING
                                    {
                                        ServiceOrderNo = item.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier,
                                        AttributeId = item.coiId,
                                        AttributeValue = item.coiIdentifier,
                                        ParentId = parentId,
                                        AttributeType = "MBM",
                                        DT_Stamp = DateTime.Now,
                                        VERSION = orderVersion
                                    });
                ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_ATTRIBUTES_VERSIONING.AddRange(listToInsert);
                ctxParser.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

> In this way we can implement left join in linq. as per above SQL Query(see above sql statement).